# naive algorithm implementation

Tags: java, algorithm

why can't the Naive algorithm have o(n) time complexity? 
This is my  Java code which gave me the expected results..
Please explain what's wrong with this...

```
import java.util.*;
class NaiveAlgo{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        System.out.print("Enter the Text : ");
        Scanner inp1=new Scanner(System.in);
        String txt=inp1.nextLine();
        int lengthT=txt.length();

        System.out.print("Enter the Pattern : ");
        Scanner inp2=new Scanner(System.in);
        String ptn=inp2.nextLine();
        int lengthP=ptn.length();

        int i=0,j=0,index=0;

        while(j!=lengthP&& i!=lengthT){
            if(txt.charAt(i)==ptn.charAt(j)){
              i++;
              j++;
            }else{
              j=0;
              index++;
              i=index;
            }
        }

    if(index<lengthT)
            System.out.println("Index : "+index);
    else
            System.out.println("Not found ");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is giving expected results you said. Then what is the wrong?

Comment: It hasn't O(n) complexity looks like O(n²) - without realy calculating. the while is hiding a nested loop. (And skimming over it I am not sure if this is realy naive )

Comment: Thank you very much! Could i know the reason that u're not sure whether this is Naive? any difference in my logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is not of O(n) complexity. It's not performing a linear search -- this happened when you reset `j=0` and `i=index` when the characters don't match.

It won't be efficient with an exaggerated worst-case input of say `ptn=xxxxy` and `txt=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy`, which will cause it to be O(nm) I believe. The logic in the algorithm resets the counter for `ptn`, and only increments the index of `txt` by 1.

You can compare your execution to the `Boyer–Moore` sub-string search algorithm and see how different it is to yours:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm

Comment: Thank you very much!!  plz could i know why did you say that it wont be efficient? Since it's Naive so that it  has O(n^2) complexity or this code is difference from Naive algo in someway?

Comment: Think about the definition of a 'naive algorithm', what does it mean? I would say that it is like the first method a child would think of to solve a problem -- it will get the job done, but it will probably not be the 'best' solution. It will eventually solve the given problem, but what was the time and memory spent to do so? The naive algorithm is one where it is not efficient in terms of time (and perhaps also memory). That's where the big O notation comes in -- it's a standardized way of denoting time and space complexity.

Comment: By the way, if this answer helped do accept this as the solution (tick symbol beside my answer) so that we can close this. If there are anything else you would like to clarify we can take this into chat -- don't want to have too long comment bodies.